# jwplayer - how do I get video duration before playback?

Tags: jwplayer

I'm trying to get the duration of a video before the jwplayer starts playing. I tried calling getDuration () in the onReady event callback, but it returns -1. When I call getDuration () in the onPlay event callback, I get the correct value. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
<video src="movie.mp4" id="video" width="800" height="600"></video>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer ('video').setup ({
    flashplayer: '/js/mediaplayer-5.10/player.swf',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    events: {
        onReady: function () {
            var duration = this.getDuration();
            alert ('ready, duration: ' + duration);
        },
        onPlay: function (state) {
            alert ('play, duration: ' + this.getDuration());
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is approximately how I have handled this problem:

```
var duration = 0;
jwplayer().onReady(function() {
  if (duration == 0) {
    // we don't have a duration yet, so start playing
    jwplayer().play();
  }
});

jwPlayer().onTime(function() {
  if (duration == 0) {
    // we don't have a duration, so it's playing so we can discover it...
    duration = jwplayer().getDuration();
    jwplayer().stop();
    // do something with duration here
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Everybody to follow this approach. It is the only solution. Many thanks to Scott.

Answer (score 3):

Its true. I did not get any solution for that so i used two events. OnBuffer and OnPlay like below. It provides -1 in first event and real length in second event. It might be helpful. Well i am looking for any other solution if exits.

```
           var duration;  
           jwplayer().onBuffer(function () {
            duration = this.getDuration();              
            alert(duration);
            }       
    );

    jwplayer().onPlay(function () {
            if(duration==-1)
            duration=this.getDuration();
            alert(duration);
            }       
    );
```

Comment: I will be revisiting this problem soon, but I'm wondering if it has to do with setting up streaming on the server. I'm guessing that if you do setup streaming, you might get the correct value from the getDuration() method.

Answer (score 1):

JW Player will only show duration when video is playing

```
$.each(all_video_ids, function(video_idx, video_id){
        console.log(video_id);
        var temp_video = jwplayer(video_id);

        var metaData = temp_video.getMeta();
        console.log(metaData);
        console.log(temp_video);
        console.log(temp_video.getDuration());

        if(temp_video.getState() == "PLAYING"){
            temp_video.pause();
        }
    });
```

Comment: it returns the proper duration under more conditions than just playing. see https://gist.github.com/s2t2/45460c06581798ba6e94 for diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Just heads up in this question guys recently i analysed other video player as well and all the video player except you tube are showing video duration initially as 00:00:00
Most probably youtube is saving the duration in DB and Showing it

Otherwise @Scott Evernden idea makes more sense

http://mediaelementjs.com/, http://www.videojs.com/ and mostly other site except youtube has duration as 00:00:00
jwplayer also like other player provide video duration after play event.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getDuration` doesn't seem to work unless the video is actively playing (not even when paused). I do this:

```javascript
onPlay: function(){
    var obj = this; //save a reference to 'this' jw object for reference in the setInterval callback.
    if (!obj.playBegan){ //we only want this to trigger once when play begins (not on seek or ffd)
        obj.playBegan = true;
        obj.durationProcessor = setInterval(function(){
             if (obj.getDuration() !== -1){ //sometimes the movie duration isn't immediately available.
                 clearTimeout(obj.durationProcessor);
                 console.log(obj.getDuration());
             }
        }, 250); //look for a duration every .25 seconds

    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the duration when player gets ready and fetch the value of right controller like :

```
  var duration = $('.jw-group.jw-controlbar-right-group.jw-reset')[0];
  var spanText = $(duration).children('.jw-text.jw-reset.jw-text-duration')
  youTubeVideoDuration = ($(spanText)[0]);
```

it will fetch the duration from player 
if you wish to convert it into relative time ie in seconds then you can use the function

```
function toseconds(hms) {
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons
if (a.length == 3)
    return ((+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2])); // if video is in hrs
else
    return ((+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1])); // video is in minutes
}
```