# Total time and time elapsed in JWPlayer - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwplayer, duration

I need

1. total duration of the video
2. number of seconds played till now

I think I can get the second part using [jwplayer - how do I get video duration before playback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438047/jwplayer-how-do-i-get-video-duration-before-playback)

Can someone please help me with the first part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the these information from [JWPlayer API reference](http://sdk.jwplayer.com/ios/docs/reference/Classes/JWPlayerController.html) itself.

1. Use [duration](http://sdk.jwplayer.com/ios/docs/reference/Classes/JWPlayerController.html#//api/name/duration) property for getting the total duration of video
2. Use [playbackPosition](http://sdk.jwplayer.com/ios/docs/reference/Classes/JWPlayerController.html#//api/name/playbackPosition) property for getting the elapsed time

**Usage:**

```
double duration = [jwPlayer duration];
NSNumber *time  = [jwPlayer playbackPosition];
```